# How to deselect Particular value in Bootstrap mutiselect JS?

Tags: javascript

How to deselect particular value in boostarp multiselect Js?I want to deselect Any option when user Click All Options it will select All options it's working fine,But When Click All option Any option do unchecked.
Below My Coding.

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="multiselect-all">
                Select all
            </label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="cheese">
                Cheese
            </label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="multiselect-all">
                Any
            </label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="multiselect-all">
                Pizza
            </label>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this-  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mEBOrx

Comment: and the code which you provided is incomplete,please complete code

Comment: Plz refer my above code

Comment: i couldn't replicate the issue in the codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLGWgL

Comment: Plz refer my above code Yes,Like odepen.io/nagasai/pen/mEBOrx  But i want to Show Count always ,not showing any option in above,User click one option above Show Selected 1

Comment: It's not working,http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLGWgL